# How do i deploy a react app to Azure Static Apps with Node backend and redis cache?

Tags: node.js, azure, redis

Ive been developing a react app locally, which is running Ubuntu (WSL2) and hosting redis which i use for caching. My backend is nodejs which has some config details to connect to redis - in my case its using localhost to connect.
My react app also is serviced by nodejs which does all my api calls.

How do i set this up in azure static web apps? The react stuff deploys, but i can't work out how to do the rest.

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: Code of Radis with react add [nodes](https://i.imgur.com/8ZO4M6v.png) local [Output](https://i.imgur.com/e7HyfIk.png)  git [status](https://i.imgur.com/1Nl5BuS.png), azure static web [app](https://i.imgur.com/s47mGIG.png) Output

Answer (score 0):

The steps for deploying a React app to Azure Static Apps with a Node.js backend and Redis cache:

- create a new React application using Create React App

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

- The below react app  to fetch data from an endpoint (`/testCache`) and display the response, assuming it's in a specific format.

```js
// App.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("/testCache");
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Redis Cache Test</h1>
      {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
      {data && (
        <div>
          <p>Cache response - PING: {data.pingResponse}</p>
          <p>Cache response - GET Message: {data.getMessageResponse}</p>
          <p>Cache response - SET Message: {data.setMessageResponse}</p>
          <p>Cache response - GET Message again: {data.getMessageAgainResponse}</p>
          <p>Cache response - CLIENT LIST: {data.clientListResponse}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

- Add an API to Azure Static Web Apps using Azure [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=react).
- Create Azure Functions to serve as your Node.js backend. Azure Functions can be used to handle API requests from your React app.
  The backend API endpoint code below interacts with a Redis cache..

```js
const cacheConnection = redis.createClient({

url: `rediss://${cacheHostName}:6380`,

password: cachePassword

});

await cacheConnection.connect();

try {

// PING command

const pingResponse = await cacheConnection.ping();

  

// GET Message

const getMessageResponse = await cacheConnection.get("Message");

  

// SET Message

const setMessageResponse = await cacheConnection.set("Message", "Hello! The cache is working from Node.js!");

  

// GET Message again

const getMessageAgainResponse = await cacheConnection.get("Message");

  

// CLIENT LIST

const clientListResponse = await cacheConnection.sendCommand(["CLIENT", "LIST"]);

  

res.json({

pingResponse,

getMessageResponse,

setMessageResponse,

getMessageAgainResponse,

clientListResponse

});

} catch (error) {

res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });

} finally {

cacheConnection.quit(); // Close the Redis client connection

}

});
```

**Local:**

[image]

**git status:**

Push your React app code to a Git repository. Configure Azure Static Web Apps with your repository and specify the build settings.

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]